# Como posso testar se um Response do Nodejs ainda está vivo

Tags: node.js, request

Eu tenho um `Response` do NodeJS(Express), como posso testar se ele ainda está vivo ?

```
let responses = []

app.get('/', async function (req, res) {
  responses.push(res)
});

setInterval(() => {
    responses.forEach(res => {
       if('Aqui eu quero testar se a conexão ainda está viva'){
           res.write('Cadeia de bytes aqui')
       }
    })
}, 100)
```

Nesses `write()` eu envio chunks de audios, para testar isso eu passo a url da stream pelo VLC, e quando fecho o VLC, eu preciso remover ele da lista.

Answer (score 3):

Segundo a documentação de [Express 4.x `res.end()`](https://expressjs.com/pt-br/api.html#res.end) deriva diretamente de [`response.end()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding_callback) do núcleo do Node em [`http.ServerResponse`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse)

Você pode verificar a propriedade [`response.finished`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_finished) que retorna um `Boolean` "true" caso `response.end()` for chamado.

Eu não tentei reproduzir seu código más um snippet possível seria algo como:

```
while(true){
    responses.forEach(res => {
       if ( !res.finished ) {
           res.write('Cadeia de bytes aqui')
       }
    })
}
```

Você verificaria se a resposta "ainda não terminou" ou seja, o `Boolean` ainda seria "false" (caso falso ... escreva|use)

Comment: Acredtio que while (true) faria o servidor parar de funcionar. Mas de qualquer forma, res.finished realmente é uma opção válida, e acho que req.complete também.

Comment: @JulioCesarHintzedosSantos, espero que aquele `while` seja só exemplo mesmo. Não sei de onde vc encontrou sua referencia (**req.complete**), seria de [http.IncomingMessage](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_complete) e suas mensagens ... se for este o caso acho que não serve a pergunta pois ela trata apenas das respostas `http.ServerResponse`

Comment: Acho que você está certo. Talvez meu comentário não seja pertinente (e nem recomendável, nesse caso) de seguir, pois eu não tirei o req.complete de nenhuma documentação, e sim de um teste que eu fiz no meu computador (depois do request ser respondido, o objeto ganha uma propriedade chamada "complete", com o valor true).

Comment: @LauroMoraes Testei com o `res.finished` e não funcionou, ele não consegue identificar que a conexão foi terminada.

Answer (score 3):

A resposta do Lauro está correta, mas seu código não vai funcionar justamente pelo `while (true)`.

Para criar um loop assíncrono, você pode utilizar recursão com setTimeout:

```js
let app = require('express')();
let responses = []

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    // o res.count que eu criei serve apenas para finalizar
    // o chamado depois de 5 iterações
    // dessa forma da pra testar pelo navegador, que só mostra
    // a resposta quando o pedido for finalizado
    res.count = 0;
    responses.push(res)
});

app.listen(2000);

// função recursiva
function responder() {

    // 'programa' uma função para ser executada daqui a 1000 ms
    setTimeout(() => {
        responses.filter(res => !res.finished).forEach(res => {
            res.count++;
            res.write('Cadeia de bytes aqui');

            // a partir de agora o res.finished será true
            if (res.count === 5) res.end();
        });

        // quando finalizar a função, chama responder novamente
        responder();
    }, 1000);

}

// inicializa o loop
responder();
```

Lembrando que javascript roda em apenas um núcleo. Funções assíncronas não rodam em núcleos diferentes, e sim no núcleo principal assim como o resto do seu código. A diferença é que as funções assíncronas são executadas depois que todo o seu código síncrono é executado.

Por isso o `while (true)` impede qualquer outro código assíncrono de ser executado: ele é síncrono e infinito.

Comment: O while, foi só um exemplo, na verdade um uso um `setInterval`, porém mesmo com o set interval não funcionou.
Oque eu fiz foi o seguinte, abri o VLC, passei minha rota `http://localhost:8080/`, ele toca normalmente, porém quando eu dou pause ou fecho o VLC ele continua com o `finished`como `false`.

Comment: Você gostaria de fazer tipo um controle remoto, então? Acho que não posso lhe ajudar nesse caso. Mas atualiza a sua pergunta e coloca essas informações.